# php with soap service

Tags: php, xml, soap

i need to use this xml file:
http://www.mubashermisr.com/Mubadelayed/Service1.asmx?WSDL

to connect to **GetTopGainers** methode 
i use this code:

```
    <?php
    ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0"); // disabling WSDL cache
    $wsdl_path = "http://www.mubashermisr.com/Mubadelayed/Service1.asmx?WSDL";

    $parameters = array("Username"=>"xxxx","Password"=>"xxxx","ID"=>"xxxxx");

    $client = new SoapClient($wsdl_path, array('trace' => 1));

    try {
    $result = $client->GetTopGainers($parameters);
    print_r($result);
   }
    catch (SoapFault $exception) {
    echo $exception;      
    } 

   ?>
```

But i get the following error:

```
SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] Server was unable to process request.
     ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. in 
C:\wamp\www\soap\soap.php:24 Stack trace: #0 
C:\wamp\www\soap\soap.php(24): SoapClient->__call('GetTopGainers', Array) 
#1 C:\wamp\www\soap\soap.php(24): SoapClient->GetTopGainers(Array) #2 
{main}
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Here is the eroor:SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. in C:\wamp\www\soap\soap.php:24 Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp\www\soap\soap.php(24): SoapClient->__call('GetTopGainers', Array) #1 C:\wamp\www\soap\soap.php(24): SoapClient->GetTopGainers(Array) #2 {main}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <?php
    ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0"); // disabling WSDL cache
    $wsdl_path = "URL";

    $parameters = array("Username"=>"xxx","Password"=>"xxx","ID"=>"xxx");

   $header = new SOAPHeader('Namespace', 'Auth', $parameters);
   $client = new SoapClient($wsdl_path);

   $client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
   try {
    $topGainers = $client->GetTopGainers(); // Top Gainers

    echo"<pre>";
    print_r($topGainers);
    echo"</pre>";
    }
    catch (SoapFault $exception) {
    echo $exception;      
    } 

    ?>
```